# Wine 1.6.2 sound not working

Tags: sound, wine

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 and a Wine 1.6.2. I successfully installed and ran GTA III from it and it works, except that there is no audio. I changed the setting from "speaker" to "headphone"(what I use) and even tried changing the in-game hardware options. It should be noted that I have never used Wine before this so it would most probably be a problem regarding Wine.

Answer (score 2):

Wine is notorious for having problems with Pulseaudio, Ubuntu's default sound server. As a result, it is necessary for you to switch to ALSA. To do that, follow the below instructions.

1. Run `sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio` from terminal
2. Run `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`

Done! You can find more information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157931/ubuntu-12-04-replacing-pulseaudio-with-alsa).

Additionally, Wine 1.6.2 seems to be outdated. Since you are trying to run games, you probably want the latest version. To install it, follow the below steps.

1. Run `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
2. When asked, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Run `sudo apt-get remove wine wine1.6`
4. Run `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

After that, you should be running the latest Wine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I installed alsamixer, do I have to add it in Wine's settings or does it work without anything? In Wine's audio settings, I am unable to find it. I can only see "Default System" and pulseaudio.

Comment: From my experience, it works out of the box, provided it is your system default.